# Are the texture buffers flushed when an OpenGL ES (iPhone) context gets deallocated?

Tags: iphone, memory, opengl-es, textures

Or I have to glDeleteTextures, glDeleteTextures one by one them?
Or is there some kind of glDeleteAllTextures like function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textures (and other OpenGL ES resources) are managed by EAGLSharegroup objects. These objects are created for you automatically when you create your EAGLContext objects and disposed of when the EAGLContext objects are released.

So the short answer to your question is: no, you don't have to delete all the textures before you release your context.